# How do I reduce stutter when repeatedly printing in the console in python?

Tags: python, console

I have the following sample of code:

```py
import time
# import sys


i = 0
right = True
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if i == 30:
        right = False
    elif i == 0:
        right = True

    if right:
        i += 1
    else:
        i-= 1

    
    text = ''''''
    for j in range(10):
        text += str("." * int(30-i-j)) + "x" + "\n"
    print(text)
    # sys.stdin.write(text)
```

[Video of output](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFVJuls7qc/1wENKQQAR7KwILckKot3bg/watch?utm_content=DAFVJuls7qc&utm_campaign=celebratory_first_publish&utm_medium=link&utm_source=celebratory_first_publish)

The output is expected, but there is clearly some staggering after each input. Is there any way to reduce this? I've already tried to use the apparently more efficient sys.stdin.write, but it doesn't seem to work with variables as a I get an error with I do.

I am using VS Code for my IDE.

Comment: That's just your terminal not scrolling fast enough. Nothing to do with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using your OS's native terminal?

VSCode runs in Electron, so performance would be slower. They did make the terminal rendering [faster](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/10/03/terminal-renderer) a while back, but OS terminals are as optimized as it gets afaik, so if you want good performance try that

Comment: Hey, thanks. I sent you a message on instagram, mind checking it out?